# Is there a place that i execute my mysql faster than my laptop?

Tags: mysql, performance, execution

I have a table about 640,000 rows, let's call this '`reference`'

Another table about 780,000 rows, let's call this '`data`'

Then I have another table of 1 row, let's call this table '`range`'.

There are no indexes on any of the tables just raw data...I don't know if adding indexes will make anything faster since I am just performing math on all rows.

I have a stored procedure that has a cursor that selects from data,range to fetch numbers in row by row (72 columns to perform math on).
then for each row as the cursor run...
I compute the following

```
INSERT INTO results(ID,info,score)
    SELECT ID, info,
                -ABS(_C1 - C1 )/R_C1
                -ABS(_C2 - C2 )/R_C2
                -ABS(_C3 - C3 )/R_C3
                ...
                -ABS(_C70 - C70 )/R_C70
                -ABS(_C71 - C71 )/R_C71
                -ABS(_C72 - C72 )/R_C72
            as score
        FROM reference
        ORDER BY score desc
        LIMIT 1;
```

where

_C#'s are fetched data from `data` table(by cursor)

R_C#'s are fetched from `range` table(by cursor) and

C#'s are columns from `reference` table.

So basically i just want one row for each ID from the `data` table that has the maximum score value calculated using all those columns.

In the stored procedure, i have a counter that is incremented and selected to be outputted to screen as it runs...

On my laptop it takes about a minute to the counter to increment so i am guessing it takes about that long to insert a single row.

By my calculations, 780,000 rows from data table would take about 541.7 days.
Which is INSANE...

Any suggestion to speed this up?
Or is there a site that have powerful server or something that can run this faster?

here's my cursor declare

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT 
    t.ID,t.info,t.C1,t.C2,t.C3,t.C4,t.C5,t.C6,t.C7,t.C8,t.C9,t.C10,t.C11,t.C12,t.C13,t.C14,t.C15,t.C16,t.C17,t.C18,t.C19,t.C20,t.C21,t.C22,t.C23,t.C24,t.C25,t.C26,t.C27,t.C28,t.C29,t.C30,t.C31,t.C32,t.C33,t.C34,t.C35,t.C36,t.C37,t.C38,t.C39,t.C40,t.C41,t.C42,t.C43,t.C44,t.C45,t.C46,t.C47,t.C48,t.C49,t.C50,t.C51,t.C52,t.C53,t.C54,t.C55,t.C56,t.C57,t.C58,t.C59,t.C60,t.C61,t.C62,t.C63,t.C64,t.C65,t.C66,t.C67,t.C68,t.C69,t.C70,t.C71,t.C72,
m.C1,m.C2,m.C3,m.C4,m.C5,m.C6,m.C7,m.C8,m.C9,m.C10,m.C11,m.C12,m.C13,m.C14,m.C15,m.C16,m.C17,m.C18,m.C19,m.C20,m.C21,m.C22,m.C23,m.C24,m.C25,m.C26,m.C27,m.C28,m.C29,m.C30,m.C31,m.C32,m.C33,m.C34,m.C35,m.C36,m.C37,m.C38,m.C39,m.C40,m.C41,m.C42,m.C43,m.C44,m.C45,m.C46,m.C47,m.C48,m.C49,m.C50,m.C51,m.C52,m.C53,m.C54,m.C55,m.C56,m.C57,m.C58,m.C59,m.C60,m.C61,m.C62,m.C63,m.C64,m.C65,m.C66,m.C67,m.C68,m.C69,m.C70,m.C71,m.C72,m.C72
    FROM data t,range m;
```

Comment: why are you using a cursor. I think it is a good question tho (potentially).

Comment: Something is extremely wrong if a single insert of a single row takes a minute. It sounds like you are doing some sort of massively looping cursors, but you haven't given enough information to diagnose the real problem.

Comment: I am using cursor because if i calculate everything using a query it would create 640,000 x 780,000 rows of data which i don't think my computer has enough space to store.

Comment: Let me put it this way. A cursor is the slow road to China. Using a good index scheme, the third comment above is not true. A cursor (note the cursor that we do not know about based on your question as posed) can easily force a pseudo table scan. It is not that cursors have to be slow, but they fly in the face of fast daemon resolution by saying "here is my procedural minset, and I force it upon you"

Comment: Post table schemas, a small amount of sample data, and the results you'd expect to get from that data. *My poorly written SQL, when used with data I'm only going to vaguely describe based on a cursor I won't include information about performs slowly. How can I fix it?* is simply unanswerable. As to your question about a site where you can run it, that portion of your question is off-topic here - we don't find or recommend sites, links, books, or any other off-site information.

Comment: Okay so i guess I  need help indexing, but i don't know what to index...and 
that i don't know if 640,000 x 780,000 rows x 72 is columns of mixtures DECIMALS(20,10) and BIGINT would fit on my 206 Gig available harddrive space.

Comment: Have you considered to perform *2 updates* and measure the time as well?  One action taking 1 minute does not mean *every action itself* takes 1 minute. Once your "big tables" are in memory, it might finish in a split second. Thus, inserting 2 records might take 60.0025 seconds.

Comment: forget the insert/update aspect. Just focus on "why does my cursor stink"

Comment: I only have 4 GB DDR3 memory (it's a laptop)...if that limits anything.

Comment: I don't update anything so i am not sure what you mean by performing 2 updates?

Comment: never mind, thought you are just inserted a single row, and estimating the overall duration based on that.

Comment: i am inserting a single row but for each fetch from data,range
and calculating scores for all rows in reference, then grab just the row with highest score.

Comment: I have updated the question with my simple declare cursor statement, it's just simple select from 2 tables but range table only has 1 row.

Comment: You know like all of use are rolling our eyes over that cursor you just published wondering, gosh, should we discuss what you are putting in those columns?

Comment: Cursors are slow; don't use them if a single SELECT can do the job.

Comment: Normalize those values - divide all Cs by R_Cs. It saves 36*10^12 dividing. Export it and make C++ program to calculate it. You should be able to calculate it in half a day on Your laptop. Faster if You throw more hardware on it, it is perfectly parallelizable. Chances are, it can be calculated even faster on graphics card, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

Either your unseen cursor runs like a dog (cursors are notoriously slow), or the table `reference` has no index on column `score`.

If it is the latter, then in order to resolve the `limit 1`, a table scan is forced due to `order by score desc`

Cursors are cute, but should be used as a last resort. Think index scheming to get out of this one.

**Edit**:

Having seen your published cursor `select`, you are doing a **cartesian product**. All permutations. So a table with `m` rows and a table with `n` rows with a cartesian product returns `m*n` rows. We are yet to see your indexes from either table (but that is irrelevant on a cross join, cartesian product)

Comment: score is computed, it doesn't exist, i can't index that? can I?

Comment: in theory you could have a *covering index* on the whole chunk. [Percona Covering Index article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/). Yeehaw, no datapage lookups

Comment: btw there is nothing shabby about your hardware as I see it. It is far from inadequate

Comment: I think you need to ask if I have 3 rows, and I have 5 rows, why I need to do a cartesian product of 15 rows to do that math above. Sadly, in your case, it is not 15, it is **499.2 Trillion**

Comment: what do you mean by covering index on the whole chunk? like add an index that is combined with all 72 columns?

Comment: it's like if i had 3 houses and 5 stores, for each store, i want to know which house is closest/furthest from the store...don't i have to do a cartesian product?

Comment: read my comment above with the bolded number. 640k x 780k = 499T

Comment: I guess that's why i am using a cursor to only grab 1 row of result for each row in `data`...so i don't have 499T of data laying around which probably won't fit on my harddrive.

Comment: Well tried to drag it into chat to not pollute this space, but I don't see how you are only grabbing 1 row from `data`. Here is how I see it. The cursor does a cartesian. That is stored in memory or cached to disk. 500 Trillion rows. Then you are doing a query with a calc and an order by and a limit 1. The whole order by needs to be resolved to get the top-most 1 row. I could be wrong, and would appreciate peer-bashing. But that is how I see it. I realize there are times when a cartesian is necessary. Sadly your counts are what they are.

Comment: I think a bigger question is something like "what are you trying to achieve by these two tables?" As such, perhaps someone can craft a better solution for you. So it is a high-level business question ... we step back from potentially an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: table range only has 1 row...i have now removed the cartesian product of the cursor and just added an extra select to grab values from range table into variables.

Is there a better way to grab the `info` column of the highest `score` calculated value without sorting the whole thing?

Comment: i am not sure what "table range has only 1 row." means. As for the last half of question, no as I see it. You want them sorted afterall. Please address the question 2 comments up. Let is not get mired into this as a solution

Comment: there is no way that a Business Requirement addressed by a Technical Solution should take 541 days to run on that dataset. So as far as I am concerned, that solution is off the table. So walk around the block, gets some fresh air. Maybe some sleep. And describe the process. You have rep. You might not have sleep.